# lightGBM: Valid_sets predictions are not reproducible

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm

I am creating a model with lightGBM v3.1.1 in Python.
I used Optuna to explore the parameters and got the following values:

```
params = {'objective': 'regression',
          'metric': 'rmse',
          'verbosity': -1,
          'boosting_type': 'gbdt',
          'max_bin': 11,
          'max_depth': 5,
          'learning_rate': 0.1,
          'min_child_samples': 10,
          'seed': 123,
          'feature_pre_filter': False,
          'lambda_l1': 2.7055300945385866e-08,
          'lambda_l2': 1.1875908147914059e-07,
          'num_leaves': 31,
          'feature_fraction': 0.9272727272727272,
          'bagging_fraction': 0.4377408640572196,
          'bagging_freq': 6}
```

The datasets for training and validation were created as follows:

```
lgb_train = lgb.Dataset(data=X_train, label=y_train)
lgb_test = lgb.Dataset(data=X_test, label=y_test, reference=lgb_train)
```

The training was done as follows.

```
evaluation_results  = {}
gbm = lgb.train(
    params=params,
    train_set = lgb_train,
    valid_sets=[lgb_train, lgb_test],
    valid_names=['Train', 'Valid'],
    num_boost_round=2000,
    early_stopping_rounds=200,
    verbose_eval=10,
    feval = my_r2_score,
    evals_result = evaluation_results,
    keep_training_booster=True,
)
```

The following function is used to calculate the R2 score.

```
def my_r2_score(preds, data):
    y_true = data.get_label()
    y_pred = np.where(preds < 0, 0, preds)
    R2 = r2_score(y_true, y_pred)

    return 'R2', R2, True
```

The verbose output was as follows. Note that the r2 score of the validation sets is 0.908...

```
[LightGBM] [Warning] Accuracy may be bad since you didn't explicitly set num_leaves OR 2^max_depth > num_leaves. (num_leaves=31).
Training until validation scores don't improve for 200 rounds
[10]    Train's rmse: 52.1459   Train's R2: -2.80291    Valid's rmse: 53.1739   Valid's R2: -2.20632
[20]    Train's rmse: 52.1459   Train's R2: -2.80291    Valid's rmse: 53.1739   Valid's R2: -2.20632
[30]    Train's rmse: 52.1459   Train's R2: -2.80291    Valid's rmse: 53.1739   Valid's R2: -2.20632
[40]    Train's rmse: 52.1459   Train's R2: -2.80291    Valid's rmse: 53.1739   Valid's R2: -2.20632
[50]    Train's rmse: 52.1459   Train's R2: -2.80291    Valid's rmse: 53.1739   Valid's R2: -2.20632
[60]    Train's rmse: 52.1459   Train's R2: -2.80291    Valid's rmse: 53.1739   Valid's R2: -2.20632
[70]    Train's rmse: 32.017    Train's R2: -0.433623   Valid's rmse: 32.2842   Valid's R2: -0.18192
[80]    Train's rmse: 24.1125   Train's R2: 0.186874    Valid's rmse: 25.5191   Valid's R2: 0.261519
[90]    Train's rmse: 18.4517   Train's R2: 0.523848    Valid's rmse: 20.2805   Valid's R2: 0.53359
[100]   Train's rmse: 15.1617   Train's R2: 0.678508    Valid's rmse: 18.6286   Valid's R2: 0.606477
...
[1000]  Train's rmse: 2.46019   Train's R2: 0.991535    Valid's rmse: 9.35062   Valid's R2: 0.900851
[1010]  Train's rmse: 2.42361   Train's R2: 0.991785    Valid's rmse: 9.34548   Valid's R2: 0.90096
[1020]  Train's rmse: 2.38906   Train's R2: 0.992018    Valid's rmse: 9.33087   Valid's R2: 0.901269
[1030]  Train's rmse: 2.39676   Train's R2: 0.991966    Valid's rmse: 9.27854   Valid's R2: 0.902373
[1040]  Train's rmse: 2.39676   Train's R2: 0.991966    Valid's rmse: 9.27854   Valid's R2: 0.902373
[1050]  Train's rmse: 2.32587   Train's R2: 0.992434    Valid's rmse: 9.26247   Valid's R2: 0.902711
[1060]  Train's rmse: 2.22859   Train's R2: 0.993054    Valid's rmse: 9.48976   Valid's R2: 0.897878
Early stopping, best iteration is:
[867]   Train's rmse: 2.98704   Train's R2: 0.987522    Valid's rmse: 8.97622   Valid's R2: 0.908631
```

However, when the data used for validation is used in the predict function, the scores are very different.
This problem also occurs when the training data is predicted.

```
y_train_pred = gbm.predict(X_train, num_iteration=gbm.best_iteration)
y_test_pred = gbm.predict(X_test, num_iteration=gbm.best_iteration)

print('Train_RMSE : ',np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_train,np.where(y_train_pred < 0, 0, y_train_pred))))
print('Train_R2 : ',r2_score(y_train,np.where(y_train_pred < 0, 0, y_train_pred)))
print('Test_RMSE : ',np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test,np.where(y_test_pred < 0, 0, y_test_pred))))
print('Test_R2 : ',r2_score(y_test,np.where(y_test_pred < 0, 0, y_test_pred)))

# Train_RMSE :  36.38169190538878
# Train_R2 :  -0.8511459283386191
# Test_RMSE :  40.49274115487656
# Test_R2 :  -0.8593606256352719
```

In fact, contrary to my expectation, the prediction is not doing well either.
Considering the fact that the order of the true values and the predicted values are the same, I think it might be a problem with the output of the predict function.

```
print(list(y_train))

# [0.31, 0.51, 1.63, 2.51, 15.64, 15.88, 16.34, 18.57, 22.57, 25.23, 25.72, 26.76, 34.16, 34.62, 34.89, 41.85, 47.35, 51.42, 53.77, 54.13, 54.53, 61.27, 63.4, 64.33, 65.02, 65.09, 65.26, 68.45, 70.34, 76.24, 81.44, 82.0, 90.08, 90.8]

print(y_train_pred)

# [-42.21137062 -42.5876803  -43.31970629 -40.15572661 -30.1829544
 -28.4649289  -28.28191554 -20.12112511 -23.34965759 -21.16999658
 -17.48387272 -15.26889047  -9.46770264 -18.03107688 -12.03409617
  -2.74651152   3.32581136   6.90444345   8.22034329  10.2525597
   9.66497184  17.06179049  18.95290265  18.91957477  21.54298163
  21.96186824  18.76801441  21.47902163  24.07296686  34.21581489
  35.69352109  39.98879279  44.43212373  44.57402187]

print(list(y_test))

# [2.16, 7.45, 27.17, 30.43, 46.2, 54.21, 65.93, 86.86, 88.43]

print(y_test_pred)

# [-34.33166873 -31.0656334   -0.34253524 -15.95319274  -2.61945177
  13.90965341  13.17142033  28.19411463  33.21328962]
```

I have also confirmed that the results of validation and prediction are slightly different even when the parameters are changed and training is done. (Even though I was using the same data.)

I am unable to determine if this problem is due to the settings of the Dataset, train, and predict functions or if it is a bug.
I would like to know why the results of validation and prediction are so different even though the same data is used, and how to deal with this problem.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm experiencing same problems with no idea where to dig..